# shader storage buffer sends in data wrong

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a shader storage buffer which sends one struct with one vec3 to the shader. I send it like this:

```
GLint bufMask = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT;
lightData * ld = (lightData *) glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(lightData), bufMask);
ld[0].ambient = glm::vec3(1.f, 0.5f, 1.f);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
glBindBufferBase( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, m_lightData );
```

Right now, it's just for testing, so don't wonder why it only has a size of one.

Anyway, in the shader, when I draw vec4(lights[0].ambient.x); I get black, when I draw .y I get white and when I draw .z I get grey. So it seems the elements are off by one. Why is that?

EDIT:

struct:

```
struct lightData {
    glm::vec3 ambient;
};
```

buffer generation:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &m_lightData);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, m_lightData);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(lightData), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

buffer using: see above

shader:

```
#version 430 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 result;
struct lightData {
    vec3 ambient;
};
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer BufferObject {
    lightData lights[];
};
void main() {
    result = vec4(lights[0].ambient, 1.f);
}
```

EDIT2: I tried it with a float and that worked. I went back to a vector and now it works! I have no idea what was wrong before. Sorry! Can be closed.

Comment: How do you declare `lights` in your shader(s)?  What about `lightData` in your host code?  Actually, scratch that.  Post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: To me, this looks like your the typical alignment issue, but it is hard to tell without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: @genpfault: I added more code.

Comment: @derhass: What is the typical alignment issue? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std430` will pad your struct of `vec3` out to the size of a `vec4` as-per rules **(3)** and **(9)** below:

#### [OpenGL 4.4 Core Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) - 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout - pp. 124

> > **(3)** If the member is a three-component vector with components consuming N
> >     basic machine units, the base alignment is 4N.
> >
> > **(9)** If the member is a structure, the base alignment of the structure is N, where N is the largest base alignment value of any of its members<strike>, and rounded up to the base alignment of a vec4</strike>. The individual members of this sub- structure are then assigned offsets by applying this set of rules recursively, where the base offset of the ﬁrst member of the sub-structure is equal to the aligned offset of the structure. The structure may have padding at the end; the base offset of the member following the sub-structure is rounded up to the next multiple of the base alignment of the structure.

* <sup>**NOTE**: The point about rounding up to the base alignment of a `vec4` does not apply to `std430`; if you read rule **(9)** as written, the part I crossed out actually only applies to `std140`.</sup>

Your `vec3` has base alignment of a `vec4`, so for an array of this struct to align every instance of your `vec3 ambient` to 4N it has to pad the end of your struct. You can use a different layout that packs your struct in an implementation-defined way, but it is more trouble than it is worth most of the time.

The bottom line is that GL does not much care for anything that is 3 component. Most things need to be 1, 2 or 4 and this is one situation where GL cannot hide its trouble with 3 component data types from you.

As for a solution, you can either store your data as `glm::vec4`, or add a `float` to the end of your data structure. Either way the storage requirements will be the same.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense now! I would never have thought of that. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: However, when I have 3 bools and 1 vec4, it doesn't work. Only if I put the vec4 in the beginning to the struct it works again. Why is that?

Comment: @gartenriese: It comes down to the same issue, really. `bool` has base alignment of 1N (you can put one of them anywhere you want without alignment issues). `vec4`, on the other hand has base alignment of 4N - it is very picky about where it is placed. 3 `bool`s followed by a `vec4` is wrong, because `vec4` needs to be on a 4N boundary and the 3 `bool`s end on a 3N boundary.

Comment: If I have 4 bools and 1 vec4, I don't need any padding, right?

Comment: @gartenriese: Precisely. And remember that the size of the struct as a whole needs to be a multiple of the largest base alignment for any of its members. In this case, `vec4` has the largest base alignment (4N). This means that even if you re-arranged those `bool`s GL would still have to add padding to the end of the structure because 3 `bool`s and 1 `vec4` produces 7N.

Comment: Is a float 2 wide? Because I added a float behind those 3 bools and then it was wrong again. It still seems pretty random to me.

Comment: @gartenriese: No, in the document I linked under section 7.6.2.2 the sizes of all the basic types are outlined. `bool` and `float` are both scalars consuming 1 basic machine unit (see rule **(1)**). Of course, the size of a `bool` in C++ and GLSL are two very different things. In GLSL you can assume that a machine unit is the size of a `float` / `uint` and that `bool` is the same size. In C++, `bool` is often 1 byte while `float` is 4. This is probably why you don't see `bool` or `bvec` used often in GLSL data structures ;)

Comment: Okay, I guess I did something else wrong. Thanks a lot again, this really helped me!

Comment: Shouldn't four vec4 and four bools work?

Comment: @gartenriese: At this point, you might be better off asking a new question or editing your original one... 4 `vec4` and 4 `bool` could work, but without seeing the data structure how it's implemented in C++ and in GLSL, I cannot say definitively.

Comment: Okay. Well, I just put all data I needed in vec4s, so that works now.